# Struggling with retrieving array values in PHP

Tags: php, html

Currently I am trying to determine the cost to paint for a room, 
To get the value for each room I've been trying to use an array system.

Currently on my page where users add rooms I have this initial array code

```
$_SESSION['rheight'] = $_POST['height'];
  $_SESSION['rlength'] = $_POST['length'];
  $_SESSION['rwidth'] = $_POST['width'];
  $_SESSION['rwindoor'] = $_POST['windoor'];
  $_SESSION['rname'] = $_POST['name'];
  $_SESSION['rcost'] = $_POST['zoot'];


  $_SESSION['rtotal'] = ($_SESSION['rheight'] + $_SESSION['rlength'] + $_SESSION['rwidth'] + (.75 * $_SESSION['rwindoor'])) * $_SESSION['rcost'];
  $_SESSION['Thic'] = [];

  array_push($_SESSION['room'.count($_SESSION['Thic'])] = [$_SESSION['rname'], $_SESSION['rtotal']];)
```

Then on the page where the total cost is outputted I have

```
echo $_SESSION['thic'][0]['rname'];
```

Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: Do you set any value to `$_SESSION['thic'][0]['rname']`? There is somethink like ` $_SESSION['Thic'] = [];`, but that does not have rname.

Comment: Yes I believe that should have worked on my first page, as for assigning a value to rname. But whilst inputting that data into an arrary I have failed to properly do it, hence I can't retrieve it

Comment: You are not storing anything in `'thic'` key of the array. So you would not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session_start()` function before using `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Comment: Yep Got that up the top of the page, I should have included that above!